# Banno transactions endpoint ignoring the startDate

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

The transactions endpoint is not considering the start date we provided in the request query and gives us the transactions which are more than six months older.

Example:

```
  URL: GET a/consumer/api/v0/users/XXXXXXXXXXX/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXX/transactions
  HEADER: {"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Authorization"=>"Bearer **MASKED**"}
  QUERY: {"since"=>"2022-06-12", "until"=>"2022-06-29"}
  BODY:
```

When the above request is sent we are getting transactions even from 2021-11-01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `since`, `until`, and `updatedSince` query parameters use the *ISO-8601 instant* for filtering. This means you'll have to use a format similar to: **2022-06-08T00:00:00Z** to get the filtering behavior.

Comment: We've updated the _Transactions/Details_ page with examples for the ISO-8601 instant: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/transactions/details/#/Transactions%20list/get_users__userId__accounts__accountId__transactions